# Parsing a xml string using sql

Tags: sql, xml

i am looking to parse the XML string using SQL .I like to have the data in separate columns.could some one please help?.
The string:

```
<item id="1" value="0"></item><item id="2" value="14"></item><item id="0" value="0"></item>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do it in SQL Server (e.g., v2008):

```
create table #temp (xml_data xml)

insert into #temp values ('<item id="1" value="0"></item><item id="2" value="14"></item><item id="0" value="0"></item>')

select C.value('@id', 'int') as [id]
      ,C.value('@value', 'int') as [value]
from #temp cross apply
     #temp.xml_data.nodes('item') as X(C)

drop table #temp
```

Which returns:

```
id          value
----------- -----------
1           0
2           14
0           0
```